# Find No of divisor

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming

I have 1 programming question asking to find  count of numbers between (1 and x) that is  divisible 
by 2 and factor of 2 + 3 and factor of 3 + 5 and factor of 5.

I solved it and Algo is below-

```
Total count of nos between 1 and x= sum of (
no of factor of x by '2 and factor of 2'=x/2
no of factor of x by '3 and factor of 3'=x/3
no of factor of x by '5 and factor of 5'=x/5) -common number
```

Now the problem is here to how to get those common numbers that is included in above calculation.
say for example
I have to find count of no between 1 and 30
that is divisible by above 3 and factor of them then

```
For 2 numbers are ->2,4,6,....30 
For 3 numbers are ->3,6,9...30
For 5 numbers are ->5,10,15...30
```

see here i have counted 30 in each case so i have to remove this count how to do that for a big x value 
please help

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on 2 and 3 at first. Say, `x = 30`. Now, let us find out which numbers are repeating,

```
Factors of 2 under 30: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ..., 30
Factors of 3 under 30: 3,    6, 9,     12, ..., 30
```

We can see the numbers that are divisible by both 2 and 3 (that is, divisible by 6) are repeating in both of the series. So, we have to deduct them from the answer as we are counting those number twice. So, the answer for 2 and 3 would be: ((x / 2) + (x / 3) - (x / (2 * 3))).

I hope, here is enough hint to solve this problem for 2, 3 and 5. Please ask if you need more clarification.

EDIT:
This technique is actually called [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: thnks for comment.here problem is that if i will do same with 2,3,5 then there is problem say for  2,3,5  i will do (x/2)+(2/3)+(x/5)-(x/(2*3))-(x/(2*3*5)). see here i have removed 30 in both the case (x/(2*3)) and (x/(2*3*5))

Comment: Ah, you're almost there, just made a bit mistake. If you notice, you'll see that 10 has repeated twice, both in Factor of 2 and 5. That is, we have to discard those numbers too who are divisible by (2 * 5). Same goes for, (3 / 5). We have to discard those number too.

But then a new problem arises, (2 * 3 * 5) = 30, which have appeared in three of the series. And we've removed it three times. So, again, we've too add it back.

Please, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider all numbers from 1 to x as a set. This set can be divided into subsets:

[image]

Divisible by 2, 3, 5 and none of them. Those sets intersect. Your approach is good, but needs to by slightly changed. You should also count how many numbers count by 2 and 3 at the same time, 2 and 5 etc. When you'll assure that you can fill this diagram perfectly with numbers, you're ready to code.

For example, you can instantly fill the intersection of three sets with the floor of `x/30`. Go this way (remember, it's floor each time!):

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x/6 - x/30` instead of `x/15 - x/30` ?